# How to send full entity to WCF Restful service (Post) to do an update?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, wcf-rest

Using RestfulServiceMgr class, I am able to GetProducts and GetProductById. But not sure how to do it for update product, when I need to send entire entity to WCF restful service to do the update.

**WCF Restful Service :**

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
        void UpdateProduct(Entity_Product eProduct);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
        void UpdateProductDetails(Entity_ProductDetails eProductDetails);
```

**Calling Resful Service with RestfulServiceMgr Class :**

```
  public void UpdateProduct(Entity_Product ProductData, Entity_ProductDetails ProductDetailsData)
    { 
        client.EndPoint = @Constants.Url_UpdateProduct;
        client.Method = HttpVerb.POST;
        client.PostData = "{postData: value}";
        client.MakeRequest();

        client.EndPoint = @Constants.Url_UpdateProductDetails;
        client.Method = HttpVerb.POST;
        client.PostData = "{postData: value}";
        client.MakeRequest();  
    }
```

**RestfulServiceMgr Restful Calls Helper Class :**

```
   public class RestfulServiceMgr
{
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public HttpVerb Method { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string PostData { get; set; }

    public RestfulServiceMgr()
    {
        EndPoint = "";
        Method = HttpVerb.GET;
        ContentType = "application/json";
        PostData = "";
    }
    public RestfulServiceMgr(string endpoint)
    {
        EndPoint = endpoint;
        Method = HttpVerb.GET;
        ContentType = "application/json";
        PostData = "";
    }
    public RestfulServiceMgr(string endpoint, HttpVerb method)
    {
        EndPoint = endpoint;
        Method = method;
        ContentType = "application/json";
        PostData = "";
    }

    public RestfulServiceMgr(string endpoint, HttpVerb method, string postData)
    {
        EndPoint = endpoint;
        Method = method;
        ContentType = "application/json";
        PostData = postData;
    }

    public string MakeRequest()
    {
        return MakeRequest("");
    }

    public string MakeRequest(string parameters)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint + parameters);

        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // grab the response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            return responseValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works !!!

```
        client.EndPoint = @Constants.Url_UpdateProduct;
        client.Method = HttpVerb.POST;
        client.PostData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ProductData);
        client.MakeRequest();
```